# Subversion as version-incrementor at each commit?

Tags: svn, versioning

I'd like to update the (highest) revision number to a file inside a subversion repository after each commit.

I thought of a svn version keyword, but doesn't this only get updated if the specific file was changed?

i.e. I have a file *version.php* where i have the version/revision numbers, but only update *anotherfile.php* in my commit - this won't change the version/revision information *version.php* has.

Is a commit hook my only option? If yes, any examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want some kind of $GlobalRev$ to get the global revision number into your files.

The appropriate tool you may want to look at would be [svnversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html)

You can use it as post-commit hook or in your build/deployment process to create or modify a global version file.

Also see "Where's $GlobalRev$?" in [this page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it's a client-side solution. What we really need is a server-side script...

Comment: Sure, it depends on your deployment process. How do you proceed, some ant task maybe ?

Answer (score 2):

We don't do this on commit, we do this as part of our deployment process. The deployment pulls the latest code (or a particular revision) along with the SVN revision number, puts the version in the relvent places (AssemblyInfo, PHP version file etc.) then deploys it to test/UAT/live/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Hook scripts are the only option here. You have two options to accomplish that task: Either verify that the version.php is up-to-date in a pre-commit script, as suggested by the  [subversion handbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks), or initiate another commit updating your version file in a post-commit script. You should not modify the commited files in hooks as pointed out by the handbook.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion uses a repository-wide revision numbering system (see the "Global Revision Numbers" sidebar [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch02s03.html)), so your file is already being bumped.

Comment: unfortunately, the *file* revision (**$Rev$**, etc.) is only bumped when the *file* is committed.